# Animate line in desired direction with Vivus.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, svg-animate, vivus

I'm trying to animate this line so it would start from top to bottom, and then turn right to draw itself, with Vivus.js. However, the graphic does not seem to animate and I can't figure out why..anyone has some experience with SVG draw animations perhaps? Here's the pen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mLzYyE

Code:

```
var animate = ["animate1"];

animate.forEach(function (svgId) {
    return new Vivus(svgId, {
        type: "async",
        start: "autostart",
        duration: 100
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand `Vivus.js` works only with `path` element. So in your case you should replace `rect` elements to `path`. I also changed type to `oneByOne` for sequenced animation. Here is a simplified example:

```js
var animate = ["animate1"];

animate.forEach(function (svgId) {
    return new Vivus(svgId, {
        type: 'oneByOne',
        start: "autostart",
        duration: 100
    });
});
```

```css
svg {
  height: 500px;
  width: 200px;
}

path {
  stroke-width: 3px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vivus/0.4.3/vivus.min.js"></script>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<svg version="1.1" id="animate1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
  viewBox="0 0 66.598 221.333" enable-background="new 0 0 66.598 221.333" xml:space="preserve">
 <path stroke="red" d="M0 0 l 0 20"/>
  <path stroke="red" d="M0 25 l 0 20"/>
  <path stroke="red" d="M0 50 l 0 20"/>
  <path stroke="red" d="M0 75 l 30 0"/>

</svg>
```